# Why the GetCharIndexFromPosition() doesn't return properly for last character of textbox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox textBox;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox = new TextBox() { Height = 30, Width = 200, Text = "Syncfusion Software", Font = new Font("Arial", 11) };
        textBox.MouseMove += textBox_MouseMove;
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    }

    void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectionStart = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
        textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my code, this is simple sample that i tried to get clear information about `GetCharIndexFromPosition()` method of `TextBox`.

In Mouse move, i get the char index position using the current mouse position of the textbox and set selection start of the textbox based on it. So that if i mouse move, then the selection start or caret position will be set based on the mouse move. But there was an issue with when mouse moved at the end of text, selection start is not set to last. it sets last but before.

For example, if a text box contains text "stack", then if mouse position is after the "k" then caret position should be at the end, but it displayed inbetween "c" and "k". `GetCharIndexPosition()` doesn't returns value properly for last character. Let me know solution for this

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Venkatesan R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known documented behavior. The **Remarks** section of the `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharindexfromposition(v=vs.110).aspx) contains the following **Important** note:

> If the specified location is not within the client rectangle of the control, or is beyond the last character in the control, the return value is the index of the last character.

The workaround is to use the reverse method [GetPositionFromCharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx) to adjust the returned index.

Something like this

```
void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var charIndex = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
    var charPosition = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(charIndex);
    if (e.Location.X > charPosition.X) charIndex++;
    textBox.Select(charIndex, 0);
}
```

**P.S.** As a side note, I have no idea what this method is trying to achieve, but for sure it prevents the standard text selection by mouse behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up really bothering me, so I expanded Ivan Stoev's idea to a rather overengineered method that calculates the pixel width of the last character and divides it by two to accurately emulate the same behaviour as on the other characters.

The method was written for a drag/drop scenario, where the selection is adjusted to the drop position while hovering the mouse over.

```
// Cached, so it doesn't get recalculated on each moved pixel.
private Char _textBoxLastChar = '\0';
private Int32 _textBoxLastCharHalfWidth = 0;

private void TextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
        return;
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb == null)
        return;
    Int32 textLen = tb.Text.Length;
    if (textLen > 0 && _textBoxLastChar != tb.Text[textLen - 1])
    {
        _textBoxLastChar = tb.Text[textLen - 1];
        _textBoxLastCharHalfWidth = (Int32)Math.Round(GetStringWidth(_textBoxLastChar.ToString(), tb.Font) / 2);
    }
    Point localPoint = tb.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    Int32 index = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(localPoint);
    // fix for fact it returns the last char position when you go outside text bounds.
    Int32 charPosition = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index).X;
    if (textLen != 0 && index == textLen - 1 && localPoint.X > charPosition + _textBoxLastCharHalfWidth)
        index++;
    if (!tb.Focused)
        tb.Focus();
    tb.SelectionStart = index;
    tb.SelectionLength = 0;
}

public static Double GetStringWidth(String text, Font f)
{
    //create a bmp / graphic to use MeasureString on
    Single areaSize = f.Size * 20;
    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        SizeF sizeOfString = g.MeasureString(text, f, new SizeF(areaSize, areaSize), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        return sizeOfString.Width;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you ever change the font or font size of the text box, you'll have to reset `_textBoxLastChar` back to `'\0'`.