# Why does GetCharIndexFromPosition returns every time the position of last character?

Tags: c#

I need to drag and drop a button in a text box which will insert me a specific text at mouse position. The problem is that every time when I drop the button, the text will be inserted after the last characters, but I need them where the current mouse position is.

Here is the code:

```
void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    int positionToInsert = 0;
    positionToInsert = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(positionToInsert, (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
}
```

Comment: Maybe because it's a screen point and not the point relative to the control.  Try using `Point clientPoint = tb.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, indeed.. 
That was the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`Control.DragDrop Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

> The X and Y properties of the DragEventArgs are in screen coordinates, not client coordinates. The following line of Visual C# code converts the properties to a client Point.

You need to do the following

```
positionToInsert = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(tb.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
```

Otherwise it's likely to be a point outside the control and thus return the last position as stated in the documentation for [`TextBoxBase.GetCharIndexFromPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharindexfromposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the specified location is not within the client rectangle of the control, or is beyond the last character in the control, the return value is the index of the last character.

Comment: That's annoying though... since it means you can never actually append text behind the last character.

Comment: @Nyerguds What makes you think that?

Comment: if the location is beyond the last character in the control, the return value is _the index of the last character_. That's the _start_ of that last character;  one position _before_ the end of the string. You can never put your cursor on a position that'll make it return the actual end behind the whole string. I ended up designing a workaround, but... [it's quite convoluted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658685/395685).

Answer (score 0):

> The X and Y properties of the DragEventArgs are in screen coordinates,
>   not client coordinates. The following line of Visual C# code converts
>   the properties to a client Point.

If the Coordinates of the Point specified are outside the bounds of the `TextBox`, then the method returns the index of the last character inside the text box.

To Test that, try :

```
tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(1000, 1000));
```

Solution:

```
Point clientPoint = tb.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
positionToInsert = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(clientPoint);
```